# WordPress WP_ajax not working

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Have been looked at the WP ajax documentation for hours now and still can't
figure this out. I am working on a plugin and this is for updating it's
options without having to refresh the page. I've managed to accomplish it
through wp-load, but know thats bad practice and would like to do it correctly.

I will be moving the javascript to a separate .js file, once I have everything
up and working.

All of the code is in on single page. Trying to update some options via ajax
and it just is not working. The response is saying its successful, but the
current_form option is not being updated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code is now updated to:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'AWNT_save_form_data', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/save_form_data.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

wp_localize_script( 'AWNT_save_form_data', 'MyAjax', array(
    // URL to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php to process the request
    'ajaxurl'          => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),

    // generate a nonce with a unique ID "myajax-post-comment-nonce"
    // so that you can check it later when an AJAX request is sent
    'postCommentNonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'myajax-post-comment-nonce' ),
    )
);

add_action('wp_ajax_AWNT_save', 'AWNT_save_callback');

function AWNT_save_callback() {
update_option('current_form', '5');
$nonce = $_POST['postCommentNonce'];
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'myajax-post-comment-nonce' ) )
    die ( 'Busted!');
update_option('current_form', 'foo');
echo get_option('current_form');
die();
}
```

JS file (save_form_data.js) :

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#save').click(function() { 
        var data = {
            action: 'AWNT_save',
            postCommentNonce : MyAjax.postCommentNonce,
            form_name : $('#form_name').val(),
customC: $('#customC').is(":checked"),
no_throttle: $('#no_throttle').is(":checked"),
form_code : $('#form_code').val()};

        jQuery.post( MyAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Response: ' + response);
        });
    });
});
```

Script is being added, see an alert for the response of 0, but the update_option either isn't being called or isn't working.  current_form remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should read http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/

First **separate the javascript** file and use **wp_enqueue_script** to add it.
Then use **wp_localize_script** to pass the nonce and ajaxurl to your javascript file.

**In function.php**

```
wp_localize_script( 'your-js-file', 'MyAjax', array(
    // URL to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php to process the request
    'ajaxurl'          => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),

    // generate a nonce with a unique ID "myajax-post-comment-nonce"
    // so that you can check it later when an AJAX request is sent
    'postCommentNonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'myajax-post-comment-nonce' ),
    )
);


// if both logged in and not logged in users can send this AJAX request,
// add both of these actions, otherwise add only the appropriate one
add_action( 'wp_ajax_AWNT_save', 'AWNT_save_callback' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_AWNT_save', 'AWNT_save_callback' );

function AWNT_save_callback() {

//CHeck  nonce FIRST HERE

$nonce = $_POST['postCommentNonce'];

// check to see if the submitted nonce matches with the
// generated nonce we created earlier
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'myajax-post-comment-nonce' ) )
    die ( 'Busted!')

update_option('current_form', 'foo');
echo get_option('current_form');

die();
}
```

In your javascript file

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#save').click(function() { 
        var data = {
            action: 'AWNT_save',
            postCommentNonce : MyAjax.postCommentNonce,
            form_name : $('#form_name').val(),
customC: $('#customC').is(":checked"),
no_throttle: $('#no_throttle').is(":checked"),
form_code : $('#form_code').val()};

        jQuery.post( MyAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Response: ' + response);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, still doesn't appear to be working though. Updated original question.

Comment: Sorry typo in answer .Look for add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv and see if it solves the problem

Comment: I saw :) Don't think it should, it's for a plugin options page available only to those with administrative rights. Just tried it now and still nothing. Though the script is definitely running, all of the values are correct, and it keeps responding successful. But still won't update the option with the update_option line  in the callback.

Comment: Tested also sending an email to myself through AWNT_save_callback()  and am not getting anything. Looks as if function AWNT_save_callback() is just never being called. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test(crude one) and this was the working code for me.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'AWNT_save_form_data', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/save_form_data.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'AWNT_save_form_data', 'MyAjax', array(
    // URL to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php to process the request
    'ajaxurl'          => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    // generate a nonce with a unique ID "myajax-post-comment-nonce"
    // so that you can check it later when an AJAX request is sent
    'postCommentNonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'myajax-post-comment-nonce' ),
    )
);
add_action('wp_ajax_AWNT_save', 'AWNT_save_callback');
function AWNT_save_callback() {
    update_option('current_form', '5');
    $nonce = $_POST['postCommentNonce'];
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'myajax-post-comment-nonce' ) )
        die ( 'Busted!');
    update_option('current_form', 'foo');
    echo get_option('current_form');
    die();
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_menu_pages', $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1 );
function register_menu_pages() {
    add_menu_page('AWNT', 'awnt custom', 'manage_options', 'awntCustom', 'awnt_menu', 'dashicons-admin-site', 6 );
}
function awnt_menu () {
    ?>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" id="form_name" name="form_name">
        <input type="text" id="form_code" name="form_code">
        <input type="checkbox" id="customC" name="customC">
        <input type="checkbox" id="no_throttle" name="no_throttle">
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" id="save">
    </form>
    <?php
}
```

The Javascript code was:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#save').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var data = {
            action: 'AWNT_save',
            postCommentNonce : MyAjax.postCommentNonce,
            form_name : $('#form_name').val(),
            customC: $('#customC').is(":checked"),
            no_throttle: $('#no_throttle').is(":checked"),
            form_code : $('#form_code').val()
        };
        jQuery.post( MyAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Response: ' + response);
        });
    });
});
```

I think the same should work for you unless you are having any other javascript conflicts.

Answer (score -2):

This should be

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_AWNT_save_callback', 'AWNT_save_callback' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_AWNT_save_callback', 'AWNT_save_callback' );
```

I mean the hook name is wrong.