# wp_ajax_my_action doesn't call my_action

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm stuck with a problem on my wordpress plugin. I follow the required step to use AJAX to add images on my gallery plugin, but the jQuery.post doesn't call my php functions. I use a separate file called gallery.js for the javascript part. The console log in the javascript file are displayed, but not the one in add_image_ajax_callback php function.

Here is my uploading scripts:

```
wp_enqueue_script('gallery_widget',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'gallery.js', array('jquery'));

wp_localize_script( 'gallery_widget', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

Here is my action declaration:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_image_ajax_request', 'add_image_ajax_callback' );
```

i don't need to use `wp_ajax_nopriv_add_image_ajax_request` because i have to be logged to do this action

Here is the gallery.js file:

```
$(".admin_gallery_photo_add").on("click", function() {
    console.log("click");
    var data = {
        'action':'add_image_ajax_request',
        'urlImg' : 'test'
    }

    // This does the ajax request
    jQuery.post(
        ajax_object.ajax_url,
        data,
        function(response) {
            // This outputs the result of the ajax request
            var str2 = "data action: ";
            console.log(str2.concat(data["action"]));
            var str2 = "data urlImg: ";
            console.log(str2.concat(data["urlImg"]));
        }

    );  

});
```

And finally the add_image_ajax_callback php function:

```
?>
<script>
    console.log("add_image_ajax_request"); 
    alert("lol");
</script>
<?php
echo "lol";
```

I find a post similar in this forum but there is no valid answer for me and the post was published two years ago (and i cannot comment it): [WordPress WP_ajax not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850398/wordpress-wp-ajax-not-working)

Comment: The action you are trying to execute is on dashboard side? Are you logged in to your dashboard?

Comment: Yes, no need to use the `add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_image_ajax_request', 'add_image_ajax_callback' );` if it's that you are in mind :)

Comment: Yes that was in my mind :D. Can you post the contents of `add_image_ajax_callback`

Comment: edit: i added the code in the question

Comment: Please edit your question instead

Comment: there is an error in my first comment, it's `wp_ajax_nopriv_add_image_ajax_request` and not `wp_ajax_add_image_ajax_request` we were talking about